# Remote Push-notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new to iPhone Development and I would like to know how to be able to send push notifications remotely. I have tried multiple things and I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to include more details in order for us to help you.  What is your push notification scenario and what have you tried unsuccessfully?

Answer (score 0):

Local Notification SampleCode :

[local-push-notification-sample-code-os](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.kr/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html)

[iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

---

APNS(Apple Push Notification Service)

If you're Beginner, I recommended using a UrbanAirship. 
Push services are free of 1 Million FREE Push messages/month at Basic Account.

site: [UrbanAirShip](https://urbanairship.com/), docs:[docs.urbanairship](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push)

other apns tutorial:

[Building an iOS SDK “Poke” App With APNS](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/)

---